# Python import Error : cannot import module named _counter (which is a .so file)

Tags: python-2.7, jython-2.7

I 'm using **Jython** to **execute a python script** connect_host.py which uses **paramiko** module to connect to a specified host.

paramiko module internally uses Crypto module, and **Crypto.Util module** uses **Counter.py** which in turn tries to **import _counter**,which is present in the same location Crypto.Util but as an **.so file** .

On execution, python throws the following error:

```
 File "/location/helper/connect_host.py", line 3, in <module>
    import paramiko
 File "/python/modules/paramiko/__init__.py", line 69, in <module>
    from transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
 File "/python/modules/paramiko/transport.py", line 32, in <module>
    from paramiko import util
 File "/python/modules/paramiko/util.py", line 32, in <module>
    from paramiko.common import *
  File "/python/modules/paramiko/common.py", line 98, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
  File "/python/modules/Crypto/Random/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random import _UserFriendlyRNG
  File "/python/modules/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 38, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random.Fortuna import FortunaAccumulator
  File "/python/modules/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaAccumulator.py", line 39, in <module>
    import FortunaGenerator
  File "/python/modules/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaGenerator.py", line 35, in <module>
    from Crypto.Util import Counter
  File "/python/modules/Crypto/Util/Counter.py", line 29, in <module>
    from Crypto.Util import _counter
ImportError: cannot import name _counter
```

How to make Jython load **_counter module**,which is a .so file??????

Comment: I'm not at all experienced with Jython, so I have to ask: Is there any reason to expect an `.so` file to be usable with it? That's probably a C shared library for use with CPython. I'd be more surprised it if worked than if it didn't.

Comment: You said, "python throws the error" but you're asking about Jython. Which is it?

Answer (score 0):

In [this Python documentation](https://wiki.python.org/jython/JythonFaq/GeneralInfo#Is_Jython_the_same_language_as_Python.3F) it says:

> Jython is an implementation of the Python language for the Java platform. Jython 2.7 implements the same language as CPython 2.7 ....
>
> ... Jython programs cannot currently use CPython extension modules written in C. These modules usually have files with the extension .so, .pyd or .dll.

If `import _counter`, is present in the same location as `Crypto.Util` but as an `.so` file, this would explain why it won't run from Jython.