# no viable alternative error in python with nifi executescript

Tags: python, jython, apache-nifi

I am scraping a page (e.g., facebook page ) using python script and want to pass on each post to be written to a file (something like gettwitter process). I am using Apache Nifi ExecuteScript processor to call the python script.

However, I am getting `SyntaxError: no viable alternative at input`

I can successfully transfer data between processors  but when I try to add the scrapping code I keep getting error. I am using python version 2.7.8. As I understand executeScript uses jython internally and jython can translate python code.

Below is the code which works fine with python  outside nifi if we remove the nifi related code (inner class and flow file).

```
import urllib2
import json
import datetime
import csv
import time
import sys
import traceback
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import OutputStreamCallback
from org.python.core.util import StringUtil

class WriteContentCallback(OutputStreamCallback):
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.content_text = content

    def process(self, outputStream):
        try:
            outputStream.write(StringUtil.toBytes(self.content_text))
        except:
            traceback.print_exc(file=sys.stdout)
            raise

#app_id = "<FILL IN>"
#app_secret = "<FILL IN>" # DO NOT SHARE WITH ANYONE!
page_id = "dsssssss"
#page_id = raw_input("Please Paste Public Page Name:")

#access_token = app_id + "|" + app_secret

access_token = "sdfsdfsf%sdfsdf"

#access_token = raw_input("Please Paste Your Access Token:")


def scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(page_id, access_token):
    flowFile = session.create()
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, WriteContentCallback("Hello there this is my data")
    #flowFile = session.write()
    #session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)


        has_next_page = False
        num_processed = 0   # keep a count on how many we've processed
        scrape_starttime = datetime.datetime.now()


        while has_next_page:
            print "Scraping %s Facebook Page: %s\n" % (page_id, scrape_starttime)
            has_next_page = False

        print "\nDone!\n%s Statuses Processed in %s" % \
                (num_processed, datetime.datetime.now() - scrape_starttime)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    #scrapeFacebookPageFeedStatus(page_id, access_token)
    flowFile = session.create()
    flowFile = session.write(flowFile, WriteContentCallback("Hello there this is my data")
    session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Below is the full trace of the error

```
> 2017-04-02 16:19:22,817 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10]
> o.a.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript
> ExecuteScript[id=a62f4b97-8fd7-15cd-95b9-505e1b960805]
> ExecuteScript[id=a62f4b97-8fd7-15cd-95b9-505e1b960805] failed to
> process due to org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException:
> javax.script.ScriptException: SyntaxError: no viable alternative at
> input 'has_next_page' in <script> at line number 178 at column number
> 8; rolling back session:
> org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException:
> javax.script.ScriptException: SyntaxError: no viable alternative at
> input 'has_next_page' in <script> at line number 178 at column number
> 8 2017-04-02 16:19:22,819 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-10]
> o.a.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript
> org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException:
> javax.script.ScriptException: SyntaxError: no viable alternative at
> input 'has_next_page' in <script> at line number 178 at column number
> 8
>         at org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript.onTrigger(ExecuteScript.java:214)
> ~[nifi-scripting-processors-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
>         at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1099)
> [nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
>         at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:136)
> [nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
>         at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
> [nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
>         at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132)
> [nifi-framework-core-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
>         at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
> [na:1.8.0_77]
>         at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
> [na:1.8.0_77]
>         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
> [na:1.8.0_77]
>         at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
> [na:1.8.0_77]
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
> [na:1.8.0_77]
>         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
> [na:1.8.0_77]
>         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_77] Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: SyntaxError: no viable alternative
> at input 'has_next_page' in <script> at line number 178 at column
> number 8
>         at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.scriptException(PyScriptEngine.java:190)
> ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]
>         at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.compileScript(PyScriptEngine.java:75)
> ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]
>         at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:31)
> ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]
>         at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
> ~[na:1.8.0_77]
>         at org.apache.nifi.processors.script.impl.JythonScriptEngineConfigurator.eval(JythonScriptEngineConfigurator.java:59)
> ~[nifi-scripting-processors-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
>         at org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript.onTrigger(ExecuteScript.java:204)
> ~[nifi-scripting-processors-1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2.jar:1.1.0.2.1.1.0-2]
>         ... 11 common frames omitted Caused by: org.python.core.PySyntaxError: null
>         at org.python.core.ParserFacade.fixParseError(ParserFacade.java:95)
> ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]
>         at org.python.core.ParserFacade.parseExpressionOrModule(ParserFacade.java:136)
> ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]
>         at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.compile(PythonInterpreter.java:320)
> ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]
>         at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.compile(PythonInterpreter.java:316)
> ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]
>         at org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.compile(PythonInterpreter.java:308)
> ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]
>         at org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.compileScript(PyScriptEngine.java:70)
> ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]
>         ... 15 common frames omitted
```

Appreciate your guidance. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of the script you are using, the command you use to run it and the full backtrace of the error-message you are getting?

Comment: @SB87 I have updated the original question and added the required details. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source code it appears you are missing a closing parenthesis on the following line:

```
flowFile = session.write(flowFile, WriteContentCallback("Hello there this is my data")
```

If you are still getting errors after that, it is likely that one of the imported modules contains (or depends on) native (CPython) modules rather than pure Python. The former is not supported in Jython, imported modules must be pure Python code. See [this related SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719469/import-modules-in-nifi-executescript/40722026) for more details.

Comment: thanks for your feedback. This error was due to missing closing parenthesis. I updated it and this time no compilation error but I did not receive any flow file ( 0 bytes transferred). I don't see any anything even in nifi-app.log