# NiFi: Unable to add external library to ExecuteScript Processor for Python

Tags: python, apache-nifi

I want to use Python DB client for Impala in my NiFi jython ExecuteScript Processor.

I've installed required module with `pip install impyla` and specify path to it in Module Directory field in ExecuteScript Processor.

After that I run script and got an error `javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: No module named _bitarray`

With `pip show bitarray` I found this module location and add it to the Module Directory field (use comma as a separator) and restart NiFi just in case.

But it didn't help. And I've got the same error.

After a little research I figured out that bitarray is actually a C extension.

And `_bitarray` appears in the next line of `bitarray/__init__.py`:

```
from bitarray._bitarray import _bitarray, bitdiff, bits2bytes, _sysinfo
```

In its turn `_bitarray` is stored inside `_bitarray.so` file in the same directory I specified in Module Directory.

Can someone help me how to load bitarray module?

Full stacktrace:

> 2017-07-12 15:00:57,627 ERROR [Timer-Driven Process Thread-5]
>   o.a.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript 
>   org.apache.nifi.processor.exception.ProcessException:
>   javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError: No module named _bitarray
>   in  at line number 1  at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript.onTrigger(ExecuteScript.java:214)
>   ~[nifi-scripting-processors-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]  at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1099)
>   [nifi-framework-core-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:136)
>   [nifi-framework-core-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.call(ContinuallyRunProcessorTask.java:47)
>   [nifi-framework-core-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]     at
>   org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent$1.run(TimerDrivenSchedulingAgent.java:132)
>   [nifi-framework-core-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [na:1.8.0_131]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
>   [na:1.8.0_131]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   [na:1.8.0_131]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
>   [na:1.8.0_131]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [na:1.8.0_131]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [na:1.8.0_131]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   [na:1.8.0_131] Caused by: javax.script.ScriptException: ImportError:
>   No module named _bitarray in  at line number 1    at
>   org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.scriptException(PyScriptEngine.java:202)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:42)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:31)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:264)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]   at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.script.impl.JythonScriptEngineConfigurator.eval(JythonScriptEngineConfigurator.java:59)
>   ~[nifi-scripting-processors-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]  at
>   org.apache.nifi.processors.script.ExecuteScript.onTrigger(ExecuteScript.java:204)
>   ~[nifi-scripting-processors-1.1.2.jar:1.1.2]  ... 11 common frames
>   omitted Caused by: org.python.core.PyException: null  at
>   org.python.core.Py.ImportError(Py.java:328)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.import_logic(imp.java:912)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:978)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:1062)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.ImportFunction.**call**(**builtin**.java:1280)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.PyObject.**call**(PyObject.java:431)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.**builtin**.**import**(**builtin**.java:1232)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.importFromAs(imp.java:1156)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.importFrom(imp.java:1132)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   bitarray$py.f$0(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bitarray/**init**.py:131)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   bitarray$py.call_function(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/bitarray/**init**.py) ~[na:na]   at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.createFromCode(imp.java:436)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:236)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:205)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.loadFromSource(imp.java:651)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.find_module(imp.java:543)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.import_next(imp.java:840)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:959)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:1062)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.ImportFunction.**call**(**builtin**.java:1280)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.PyObject.**call**(PyObject.java:431)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.**builtin**.**import**(**builtin**.java:1232)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.importFromAs(imp.java:1156)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.importFrom(imp.java:1132)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   impala.hiveserver2$py.f$0(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py:1211)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   impala.hiveserver2$py.call_function(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/impala/hiveserver2.py)
>   ~[na:na]  at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.createFromCode(imp.java:436)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:236)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:205)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.loadFromSource(imp.java:651)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.find_module(imp.java:543)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.PyModule.impAttr(PyModule.java:106)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.import_next(imp.java:842)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.import_logic(imp.java:904)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:978)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:1062)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.ImportFunction.**call**(**builtin**.java:1280)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.PyObject.**call**(PyObject.java:431)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.**builtin**.**import**(**builtin**.java:1232)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.importOneAs(imp.java:1099)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   impala.dbapi$py.f$0(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/impala/dbapi.py:193)
>   ~[na:na]  at
>   impala.dbapi$py.call_function(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/impala/dbapi.py)
>   ~[na:na]  at org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.createFromCode(imp.java:436)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:236)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.createFromPyClass(imp.java:205)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.loadFromSource(imp.java:651)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.find_module(imp.java:543)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.PyModule.impAttr(PyModule.java:106)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.import_next(imp.java:842)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.import_logic(imp.java:904)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.import_module_level(imp.java:978)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.importName(imp.java:1062)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.ImportFunction.**call**(**builtin**.java:1280)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.PyObject.**call**(PyObject.java:431)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.**builtin**.**import**(**builtin**.java:1232)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.importFromAs(imp.java:1156)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.imp.importFrom(imp.java:1132)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.pycode._pyx1450.f$0(:5) ~[na:na]   at
>   org.python.pycode._pyx1450.call_function() ~[na:na]   at
>   org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(PyTableCode.java:167)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.PyCode.call(PyCode.java:18)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.Py.runCode(Py.java:1386)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.**builtin**.eval(**builtin**.java:497)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.core.**builtin**.eval(**builtin**.java:501)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.eval(PythonInterpreter.java:259)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]     at
>   org.python.jsr223.PyScriptEngine.eval(PyScriptEngine.java:40)
>   ~[jython-standalone-2.7.0.jar:na]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jython can't load native (CPython, e.g.) modules, please see [this related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40722026/1668575) for more details.