# Import error No module named constant_time while accessing server

Tags: python-2.7, paramiko, apache-nifi, constant-time, python-cryptography

This is the follow up of [Import Modules in Nifi ExecuteScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719469/import-modules-in-nifi-executescript)

I am new to python as well as nifi. I am trying to execute my python script in ExecuteScript processor.

I want to access a server. so i used paramiko client. But when i run the processor, it shows "Import error No module named constant_time" at line session.write().  Though i have this constant_time.py under "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ "

[image]

I have also the path  "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ " in sys.path. I have also given this path in the "Module Directory" property.

This is my code:

```
import json, pysftp, paramiko
import java.io
from org.apache.commons.io import IOUtils
from java.nio.charset import StandardCharsets
from org.apache.nifi.processor.io import StreamCallback

class ModJSON(StreamCallback):
  def __init__(self):
    pass
  def process(self, inputStream, outputStream):

    text = IOUtils.toString(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)
    inputText = text.rstrip('\r\n')
    json_content = json.loads(inputText)
    body = ''
    try:
       body = json_content['id']['body']
       body_encoded = body.encode('utf-8')
    except (KeyError,TypeError,ValueError):
       body_encoded = ''

    ssh_client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh_client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh_client.load_system_host_keys()
    ssh_client.connect('server', username='xxx', password='xxxx')

    sftp_client = ssh_client.open_sftp()
    text_file = sftp_client.open ('/doc/body.txt', 'w')   
    text_file.write("%s"%body_encoded)
    text_file.close()
    outputStream.write(bytearray(json.dumps(body, indent=4).encode('utf-8')))

flowFile = session.get()
if (flowFile != None):
   flowFile = session.write(flowFile, ModJSON())
   flowFile = session.putAttribute(flowFile, "filename", flowFile.getAttribute('filename').split('.')[0]+'_translated.json')
   session.transfer(flowFile, REL_SUCCESS)
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Import Modules in Nifi ExecuteScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40719469/import-modules-in-nifi-executescript)

Answer (score 0):

As explained by Matt Burgess in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40722026/70465), the `ExecuteScript` processor uses *Jython*, not *Python*, so compiled modules are not available. There is ongoing discussion of how/if to add this feature.

Comment: yeah. In that discussion, it was explained how to import modules. It was said to add the lib path in "Module Directory " property in ExecuteScript Processor. I also did that adding in the "module Directory". But still it shows the error. so do you mean that i can never import such modules?

Comment: I believe that is the case currently -- as Matt wrote: "According to [this SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29814603/python-import-error-cannot-import-module-named-counter-which-is-a-so-file), paramiko uses Crypto which has native libraries, so cannot be used in Jython (see the bottom of [this post](https://funnifi.blogspot.com/2016/03/executescript-json-to-json-revisited_14.html) for my comment on that)."

Comment: Oh!!  Thanks Andy. So, is there any other module , that i can import for accessing a server?  or what is the other way around for accessing and working with server in ExecuteScript?

Comment: You have a couple options. You can try to find a Python module that does not include or depend on compiled modules, which you could use in Jython. I am unaware if any exist. You could also switch to Groovy (I'm 100% certain) or Ruby (70% certain) for the `ExecuteScript` processor, as both allow module inclusion. I cannot predict if/when NiFi Jython will accept compiled modules.

Comment: Thanks Andy let me try.